# Probability of choosing two girls from a group

Tags: probability, problem-solving

A group contain $9$ boys and $3$ girls.

For a trip, we choose randomly a group of $4$ from the group above.

What's the probability that half of the trip group will be girls?

I would like to know how to solve it without using combinatorical approach.

**My solution** :
$p=\frac{(9 ncr 2)(3 ncr 2) }{(12 ncr 4)} =\frac{12}{55} $.

Thank you.

Comment: Your approach is essentially the correct one.

Comment: @parcly Taxel- thank you, but I want to see other approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A probability approach can be used, but note that a multiplication factor will be needed.

$P(GGBB)\; in\;that\;order\; = \frac3{12}\frac2{11}\frac9{10}\frac89= \frac{2}{55}$

Since there can be $\frac{4!}{2!2!}= 6$ possible orders, ans $= \frac{12}{55}$

Comment: Thanks, and I fix the computation part.

Comment: To solve it like this, you do have to realize that all six branches have the same 2/55 probability because the numerators and denominators of the four factors will be the same although in different orders.

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain the same answer by drawing a 4 - generation tree diagram with sampling-without-replacement probabilities on all the branches. However the combinatorial approach is quicker and easier.

Comment: I agree with you, though I want to see a solution by probability approach. The tree is a bit confusing. Thank you for your time and answer.